# PHP variable in JS not working

Tags: javascript, php

I have a list of DIVs that when clicked it should hide the top div to reveal the text underneath.

It works fine, however if I try to insert the DIVs numerical ID using PHP it fails.

For example, if I do this it will apply it to the correct DIV

```
<script>
    $('.reveal2').on({
        click: function(){
            $('.remove2').css({display: 'none'});
        $('.code2').css({display: 'block'});
        }
    });
</script>
```

However if I do this, it doesnt work:

```
<?php $example = '2'; ?>

<script>
    $('.reveal<?php echo $example ?>').on({
        click: function(){
            $('.remove<?php echo $example ?>').css({display: 'none'});
        $('.code<?php echo $example ?>').css({display: 'block'});
        }
    });
</script>
```

I have created a jsfiddle of the working code here: http://jsfiddle.net/RGQaU/

I cant work out why inserting the php variable will make this not work.

Any ideas much appreciated.

UPDATE: I am using defer on jQuery library, after turning off the defer the above worked. However I need to defer jQ, I have tried wrapping the above code in window.onload, but still doesnt work.

Comment: What does the generated html source look like when you try the PHP version?

Comment: Hi Guys, its exactly the same, it outputs .reveal2, .remove2 etc etc.

Comment: You can use relative selectors like .prev() and .next() instead of targetting elements by class or ID and have a general-purpose function, instead of a pile of specific ones.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try and clean up your code, I will write that value to a js variable, like so:

```
<?php $example = '2'; ?>

<script>
    var example = "<?php echo $example ?>";
    $('.reveal'+example).on({
        click: function(){
            $('.remove'+example).css({display: 'none'});
        $('.code'+example).css({display: 'block'});
        }
    });
</script>
```

So, why you should always use this way:

1. This way you keep your problem in one place, easier to debug
2. You can always use console debug to check on the value stored in javascript variable : example
3. Those double quotes will serve you as a fallback in case you echo something like : false, null ... Preventing js errors that could stop your whole page javascript from executing.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('.remove<?php echo $example ?>')
```

Surely it's the lack of the semi-colon?

Alternatively, try this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.reveal<?php echo $example; ?>').on({
            click: function() {
                $('.remove<?php echo $example; ?>').css({display: 'none'});
                $('.code<?php echo $example; ?>').css({display: 'block');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score -5):

You quotes aren't quite right:

Change:

```
$('reveal<?php echo $example ?>').on({
```

To:

```
$('.reveal'<?php echo $example ?>).on({
```

in each spot you use it.